Proving the output voltage expression
Assume this is an ideal op-amp, we consider the bias currents in this circuit; consider also Ve = 0 :

I want to prove what they wrote in the solution :

So what i will do is using the basic tools i have KVL/KCL:
\$ i_1 + i_2 = I+ \iff \frac{V_e - V_+}{R_1} + \frac{V_s - V_+}{R_2} = I_+\$
and \$ V_- = -R_3 \cdot I_- = V_+ , V_e = 0 \iff I_+ = \frac{R_3 I_-}{R_1} + \frac{V_s + R_3 \cdot I_-}{R_2}\$ and finally \$V_s = R_2 \cdot I_+ -I_- \cdot R_3 (\frac{R_1+R_2}{R_1}) \$
What did i do wrong?
Source for everyone saying its my fault its not , here is my professor problem sheet : 

I believe there may be a significant error in the diagram. Do you have the R1+R2 divider tied to the (+) input? If that is what's really at some site or book, you should reference it because I don't think the diagram can be correctly arranged.

@periblepsis i made an edit where i showed the exercice, i cant give out the source, not that i cant but you need to access the course in classroom to see the pdf files

Thanks. You definitely copied it right. That's a problem with the course materials, then. Thanks!

What are A.L.I. ? Perhaps a calculation about "hysteresis" currents incidence?

aaah this hysteresis concept in ALI can you explain it please @Antonio51

The note added has an "error" <<< Pour mettre en evidence .... amplificateur inverseur >>>, the "figure 1" is not the real circuit of this "assembly" ... The inputs + and - must be swapped.

Ah no, that figure is the only one used throughout the problem, regardless if it was different , their solution for Vs is wrong  @Antonio51

incorrect diagram & all results incorrect
First, let me correct your picture.
The diagram below on the left is what you are showing and it won't fit your assumption that \$V_p=V_m\$. The reason is that the output responds in a positive direction to a positive difference (your \$V_d\$) and if the output moves more positively then the difference, \$V_d\$, would become still more positive.
The positive feedback loop here would not result in \$V_p=V_m\$.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The diagram above on the right does (in the ideal -- no offset voltage) meet the assumption that \$V_p=V_m\$ as now there is negative feedback being applied.
So, despite the fact that I think you followed through with valid KCL logic, you started with a false assumption. So you reached a wrong result for that reason.
But close.
And I don't think the highlighted result is correct, either.
provide sources
Which gets to an issue. When writing you questions out like this, please provide source information. Even if it isn't available via a web link it's still possible that someone may have the text and can confirm you accurately expressed it.
KCL
Here's my KCL for the right-side schematic (the correct one, not the incorrect one which only wastes time worrying over.) I usually want to apply KCL to the output pin, as well, which is why I included \$I_s\$ in my right-hand schematic. Keeps things clean (to me):
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_m}{R_1}+\frac{V_m}{R_2}+I_m&=\frac{V_s}{R_2}
\\\\
\frac{V_p}{R_3}+I_p&=0\:\text{A}
\\\\
\frac{V_s}{R_2}&=I_s+\frac{V_m}{R_2}
\end{align*}$$
Now, that's three equations and four unknowns. But \$V_p=V_m\$ is the fourth equation (ideal assumption.) So we have enough.
From that, I find that:
$$V_s=I_m\cdot R_2-I_p\cdot R_3\cdot\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)$$
This is quite close to your answer. It's just that you used a bad diagram and so assigned the wrong bias currents. But otherwise, I think you were able to move in the right direction.
added note
Since the closed loop voltage gain for the correctly wired circuit is \$A_v=-\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)\$, the above equation can be re-phrased with "lower entropy" (as Basso writes it):
$$V_s=I_m\cdot R_2+I_p\cdot A_v\cdot R_3$$
For this case, it suggests that the closed loop voltage gain arranged at the (-) input magnifies and inverts the impact of \$I_p\$ on \$R_3\$ at the (+) input.

As @periblepsis already pointed out, the schematic is wrong, opamp "inputs" are swapped.
Here is my simulation (microcap v12) with opamp Level 1 and Rout simulated.
Note that "currents" generators are in parallel, otherwise "infinite" voltages appears at opamp inputs.

And the Maple sheet to calculate ...



merci infiniment!

Pas de soucis, it is a pleasure.
